# MYSQL data type for long description, special characters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, special-characters

I have a long description field in a products table with a data type: text. The collation is latin1_swedish_ci for reference.

For products in my database I need a superscript 2, bullet points for a list and line breaks. For example when the bullet points output on the page they output as:

â€¢

Is there any way round this so i can display my long description correctly with line breaks too?

```
$product = $this->MProducts->getProduct($id);
$data['product'] = $product;

<?php echo "<p style='clear:both; padding-top:10px;'>".$product['longdesc']."</p>";?>
```

Regards,

Comment: I don't think you're looking for a type here.  Check out your form helper class in codeigniter (e.g. form_prep())  If you really are looking for type, then consider the markup that has to be included in your field as a total length.  VARCHAR or TEXT would work fine, but consider if storage is going to be a concern or not.  Small application wouldn't matter, but larger you would want to consider scaling and whatnot.

Comment: it's not a big application to be honest and neither is my description part of a form, i've edited my q as to how my long desc is displayed

Comment: How are you allowing these special characters to be input into the field?  Rich text, html, or ???  Should be able to escape it encode it going into the field and then unencode and unescape coming out.  Figured this would be somewhat built in to the helper classes in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ensure that you're retrieving the right character set from MySQL.

```
SET NAMES 'charset_name' COLLATE 'collation_name'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html

And you have to ensure that the string is unicode after you receive it.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

And you have to encode html entities if you're outputting to a browser. Specifying a charset here is important too.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Hope that helps...